# Laravel namespace error: Cannot use A as A because the name is already in use

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm facing an issue where a 'use' statement in my controller throws

```
Cannot use App\Enums\Division as Division because the name is already in use
```

The Division enum is structured as follows:

```
namespace App\Enums;

use App\Enums;

class Division extends Enum
{
...
}
```

This enum is being used in a Model as follows:

```
namespace App;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use App\Enums\Division;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Employee extends Model
{
...
}
```

The controller where this exception is thrown from has the following structure:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use App\Employee;
use App\Division;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class AttendanceController extends Controller
{
...
}
```

EmployeeController has the same structure but didn't throw any namespace collision errors

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use App\Employee; 
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Enums\Month;
use App\Division;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class EmployeeController extends Controller
{
...
}
```

I'm not sure why this is causing an issue as I use the same structure for my EmployeeController class and it's working flawlessly. **NOTE**: I also have a model called Division, hence my AttendanceController has "use App\Division", not to be confused with just the enum file.

Some suggested that I need an alias for App\Enums\Division, but my EmployeeController didn't complain and I didn't need aliasing. Others suggest that it's a php issue - I'm on 7.0.12. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: There is probably a confusion between namespace name and class name. How is Enum class declared?

Comment: Enum class is declared as: namespace App\Enums;
abstract class Enum
{...}
not sure if the formatting would look right in a comment. Also the Enum class is in a directory called app/Enums whereas all the controllers are in app/Http/Controllers

Comment: why do you use the namespace that's you are already in `use App\Enums;`?

Comment: Where is your Enum Class ?  on the first code.

Comment: @TuranZamanlı as per previous comment, the Enum class is in app/Enums (i.e. app/Enums/Enum.php). My controllers and models are in app/Http/Controllers and app/ respectively

Comment: There's a lot of "..." in these examples, making it hard to guess if there's a crucial detail that we're missing, particularly as there's apparently some unseen difference between your two controllers. Could you try to come up with a [mcve]? Try taking your code and deleting secon sections of it until the error stops happening; you may then realise the problem, and if not, you'll have a much clearer example to show us.

Comment: If Enum class is within App\Enums namespace, and so is the Division, you do not need to specify to use App\Enums in the Division PHP file.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid having the same class 'used' multiple times, alias them. Assuming `App\Division` is a model:

```
use App\Division as DivisionModel;
```

And update the references to `Division` accordingly.

Comment: Forgot to mention that I have a model called Division. Will update the question. Sorry Tom, but this didn't solve the problem

Comment: You could use aliasing to avoid namespace collisions, updated.

Comment: Yeah that was the last resort for me - I just thought I might be able to find another alternative :P. The interesting thing is that my EmployeeController has the same structure as the AttendanceController but it didn't throw any namespace collision issues. It only throws the exception when the AttendanceController is used.

Comment: And the 'imports' you've listed are the only ones used?

Comment: Yes, the imports listed are the only ones used. For your reference: namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use App\Employee;
use App\Division;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class EmployeeController extends Controller
{...}

Answer (score 1):

If Enum class is within App\Enums namespace, and so is the Division, you do not need to specify to use App\Enums in the Division PHP file. In the controller class, however, you need to specify correct paths to the classes of Enum and Division as

```
// Division file
namespace App\Enums;

class Division extends Enum
{ ... }

// Controller File
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Enums\Division; 
use App\Enums\Enum;

class AttendanceController extends Controller
{ ... }
```

Comment: While this is true, I don't think it relates to the error in the question. The extra `use` is unnecessary, but shouldn't cause an error.

Comment: I believe it does; while there’s no code for EmpoyeeController and it’s difficult to track all the unknowns, the error of the namespace stems from the Division class file.

Comment: I've corrected the unnecessary use of 'App\Enums' and as IMSoP mentioned, it doesn't solve the problem. Thanks

Comment: The problem lies in the area of confusion and mismatching of classes and namespaces. I wrote the solution that assumes that Device and Enums classes lie within App\Enums, namespace, while your code “use App\Enums” in Device class assumes that Enums class lies within App namespace.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to be sure without the full code (I'll update or delete this if better examples are added to the question), but it sounds very likely that your file contains both:

```
use App\Division;
```

and:

```
use App\Enum\Division;
```

These are both using the implicit alias `as Division`, so PHP is complaining that when it sees the word `Division`, it doesn't know which alias is meant.

The fix is to add an `as` clause to one or both lines to give them some other alias which is not ambiguous.

Comment: Hi IMSoP, to answer your comment and answer above, the full list of imports for attendance are: use Carbon\Carbon;
use App\Employee;
use App\Division;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class AttendanceController extends Controller{...}. My EmployeeController: namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use App\Employee;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Enums\Month;
use App\Division;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class EmployeeController extends Controller{...}. As you can see, not much difference. EmployeeController works fine

Comment: 2nd part. Employee model: namespace App;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use App\Enums\Division;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Employee extends Model
{...}

Comment: @KevinMugianto Please don't try to squeeze long blobs of code into comments, just edit them into the question itself. And this still contains "...", so is not actually runnable PHP code which reproduces the problem. How do we know that the problem is not in the code you've hidden in that `...`?

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue. I have solved the issue. I have used the same model name twice. So I have removed one model name and the issue is solved.